# vi editor print first word matches only

Tags: vi

I need username only be printed without  "myname" and "()"

here is the line, I am looking for "myname" only in the output in vi editor. please share the command

myname(username)

thanks

Comment: Do you want to delete the rest? Or something else?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. yes i want to delete the rest  and need 'myname' output only

Comment: Quick and dirty, assuming everything is in the same format, would be `/(<enter>D`

Comment: from this line myname(username) I am looking for myname only , the format may be varies.  next time would be the lines comes like  secondname(userid) , i am trying to get secondname  output

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to delete, on each line, the first opening parenthesis and everything after. That would be:

```
:%s/(.*//
```